# How to get the primary Google account with NativeScript?

Tags: android, nativescript

Is it possible to retrieve information about the primary Google account in Android using NativeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just same as how you would do it in Android except the syntax is JavaScript here.

Use [nativescript-permissions](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-permissions) plugin to acquire [GET_ACCOUNTS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#GET_ACCOUNTS) permissions, same should be present in your manifest too.

Then access the account manager to get the email address of google account

```
import * as app from 'tns-core-modules/application';

const accounts = android.accounts.AccountManager.get(app.android.context).getAccountsByType("com.google")
if (accounts.length) {
  const email = accounts[0].name;
}
```